# TexLive 2019 lualatex doesn't compile document

Tags: errors, luatex, texlive-2019

I have a document that compiles fine under pdflatex. But when I use lualatex the compilation process ends without doing anything.

The log file has just these line:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2019.6.18)  18 JUN 2019 09:03
 restricted system commands enabled.
**beamer-markdown.tex
(./beamer-markdown.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / logging
```

This error appears even with this minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I am running TeXLive 2019 running in ubuntu 19.04. TexLive 2018 work ok.

The output in the terminal doesn't show any error:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
```

Rebuilding the format didn't work.

But the plain TeX document

```
Hello
\bye
```

works fine.

Any idea where to start looking for clues?

**EDIT**
This is my TeXLive 2019 installation profile.

```
selected_scheme scheme-full
TEXDIR /home/zunbeltz/texlive/2019
TEXMFCONFIG $TEXMFSYSCONFIG
TEXMFHOME $TEXMFLOCAL
TEXMFLOCAL /home/zunbeltz/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /home/zunbeltz/texlive/2019/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /home/zunbeltz/texlive/2019/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR $TEXMFSYSVAR
binary_x86_64-linux 1
instopt_adjustpath 0
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 1
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 0
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 0
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 1
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 1
tlpdbopt_post_cn /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 0n /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 0
```

Comment: If lualatex wouldn't work at all, don't you think people would have noticed? So it is something special with your system or your document. Show a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, sorry for my too cryptic question.

Comment: Does a plain tex example (hello \bye) compiles with `luatex file`?

Comment: The plain TeX works fine indeed.

Comment: What happens if you add \input{luaotfload.sty} to the plain tex example?

Comment: Now, it doesn't compile. But not errors. `(./test-tex.tex
(/home/zunbeltz/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/home/zunbeltz/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex)`

Comment: Find the luatex-cache (in texmf-var normally) and move its content out of the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95051/discussion-between-textnik-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if the question has been solved, I'm having a very similar problem and I can't find a way to solve it: I can't compile with lualatex in TeXlive 2019 either.

Comment: @Aradnix I post an answer with the solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `TEXMFVAR` was defined as the same as `TEXMFSYSVAR` in `texlive.profile`. Those two folders are owed by root, so `luatex` is not able to create necessary files while compiling.

The solution is to define `TEXMFVAR` to other folder; for example, `$USR/.texlive/2019`

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't get it entirely clear how to do what you suggest.