# new install of Miktex and luatex does no longer compile

Tags: errors, luatex, miktex, installing, windows

I did a fresh install of my Windows and reinstalled MikTex and now I can no longer compile any document using luatex. This problem seems similar to this [Lualatex produces no output (MiKTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521982/lualatex-produces-no-output-miktex) and this [TexLive 2019 lualatex doesn't compile document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496275/texlive-2019-lualatex-doesnt-compile-document) and this [LuaLaTeX does not compile after upgrade to TeX Live 2020](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550325/lualatex-does-not-compile-after-upgrade-to-tex-live-2020?newreg=3aacd17365e14705af67a02ac602fa08) problem, but none of the solutions there helped me.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{paper}

\begin{document} % this command starts the document
test 
\end{document} % end the document
```

If I compile this in pdftex or xelatex, there is no problem, but in lualex I get (after like a 2 minute wait):

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (MiKTeX 21.2)
 restricted system commands enabled.

Sorry, but luahblatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\luahblatex.log

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log
```

This is the relevant part of the log file

```
2021-03-04 22:21:50,228Z INFO  luahblatex - this process (14920) started by 'texify' with command line: luahblatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-04 22:21:50,416Z INFO  luahblatex - going to create file: luahblatex.fmt
2021-03-04 22:21:50,518Z INFO  luahblatex.core - start process: initexmf --enable-installer --dump-by-name=luahblatex --engine=luahbtex
2021-03-04 22:22:29,245Z ERROR luahblatex - C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-03-04 22:22:29,246Z ERROR luahblatex - output:
2021-03-04 22:22:29,246Z ERROR luahblatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-03-04 22:22:29,246Z FATAL luahblatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-03-04 22:22:29,246Z FATAL luahblatex.core - Data: fileName="luahblatex.fmt"
2021-03-04 22:22:29,247Z FATAL luahblatex.core - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp:81
2021-03-04 22:22:29,247Z FATAL luahblatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-03-04 22:22:29,247Z FATAL luahblatex - Info: fileName="luahblatex.fmt"
2021-03-04 22:22:29,248Z FATAL luahblatex - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp
2021-03-04 22:22:29,248Z FATAL luahblatex - Line: 81
2021-03-04 22:22:29,328Z INFO  luahblatex - this process (14920) finishes with exit code 1
```

and

```
2021-03-04 22:21:51,594Z INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.3 (MiKTeX 21.2)
2021-03-04 22:21:51,595Z INFO  initexmf - this process (19044) started by 'luahblatex' with command line: initexmf --enable-installer --dump-by-name=luahblatex --engine=luahbtex
2021-03-04 22:21:51,595Z INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2021-03-04 22:21:51,624Z INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=luahbtex --dest-name=luahblatex --no-dump lualatex.ini --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2021-03-04 22:21:51,731Z INFO  initexmf.core - start process: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=luahbtex --dest-name=luahblatex --no-dump lualatex.ini --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2021-03-04 22:22:29,218Z ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2021-03-04-222229.out'
2021-03-04 22:22:29,219Z FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2021-03-04 22:22:29,220Z FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2021-03-04 22:22:29,220Z FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2021-03-04 22:22:29,220Z FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
2021-03-04 22:22:29,222Z INFO  initexmf - this process (19044) finishes with exit code 1
```

What could this be?

### EDIT (more complete log files)

*miktex/log/texify.log*

```
2021-03-05 07:32:56,799Z INFO  texify - this process (10416) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe --pdf --synctex=1 --clean my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:32:56,958Z INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:32:59,345Z INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:33:01,158Z INFO  texify - this process (10416) finishes with exit code 0
2021-03-05 07:33:18,962Z INFO  texify - this process (6512) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe --pdf --engine=luahbtex --synctex=1 --clean my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:33:19,116Z INFO  texify.core - start process: luahblatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:34:04,496Z ERROR texify.core - The system cannot find the file specified.

2021-03-05 07:34:04,496Z ERROR texify.core - Function: CopyFileW
2021-03-05 07:34:04,496Z ERROR texify.core - Result: 2
2021-03-05 07:34:04,497Z ERROR texify.core - Data: existing="my_test_file.log", path="C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.log"
2021-03-05 07:34:04,497Z ERROR texify.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:390
2021-03-05 07:34:04,498Z FATAL texify.core - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-05 07:34:04,498Z FATAL texify.core - Data: 
2021-03-05 07:34:04,498Z FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1529
2021-03-05 07:34:04,507Z FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-05 07:34:04,507Z FATAL texify - Info: 
2021-03-05 07:34:04,507Z FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2021-03-05 07:34:04,507Z FATAL texify - Line: 1529
2021-03-05 07:35:01,948Z INFO  texify - this process (6576) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe --pdf --engine=luahbtex --synctex=1 --clean my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:35:02,090Z INFO  texify.core - start process: luahblatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:35:48,130Z ERROR texify.core - The system cannot find the file specified.

2021-03-05 07:35:48,131Z ERROR texify.core - Function: CopyFileW
2021-03-05 07:35:48,131Z ERROR texify.core - Result: 2
2021-03-05 07:35:48,131Z ERROR texify.core - Data: existing="my_test_file.log", path="C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.log"
2021-03-05 07:35:48,131Z ERROR texify.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:390
2021-03-05 07:35:48,132Z FATAL texify.core - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-05 07:35:48,132Z FATAL texify.core - Data: 
2021-03-05 07:35:48,132Z FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1529
2021-03-05 07:35:48,140Z FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-05 07:35:48,140Z FATAL texify - Info: 
2021-03-05 07:35:48,140Z FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2021-03-05 07:35:48,140Z FATAL texify - Line: 1529
```

*miktex/log/luahblatex.log*

```
2021-03-05 07:35:02,908Z INFO  luahblatex - this process (6412) started by 'texify' with command line: luahblatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/laure/Documents\my_test_file.tex
2021-03-05 07:35:03,108Z INFO  luahblatex - going to create file: luahblatex.fmt
2021-03-05 07:35:03,214Z INFO  luahblatex.core - start process: initexmf --enable-installer --dump-by-name=luahblatex --engine=luahbtex
2021-03-05 07:35:48,054Z ERROR luahblatex - C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2021-03-05 07:35:48,054Z ERROR luahblatex - output:
2021-03-05 07:35:48,054Z ERROR luahblatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2021-03-05 07:35:48,054Z FATAL luahblatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-03-05 07:35:48,054Z FATAL luahblatex.core - Data: fileName="luahblatex.fmt"
2021-03-05 07:35:48,055Z FATAL luahblatex.core - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp:81
2021-03-05 07:35:48,055Z FATAL luahblatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2021-03-05 07:35:48,055Z FATAL luahblatex - Info: fileName="luahblatex.fmt"
2021-03-05 07:35:48,055Z FATAL luahblatex - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp
2021-03-05 07:35:48,055Z FATAL luahblatex - Line: 81
2021-03-05 07:35:48,096Z INFO  luahblatex - this process (6412) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: well something prevents the creation of the format. Do you have some virus or security system? Do the log-file give some clue about what could be the problem?

Comment: I just uninstalled all security systems and that did not make a difference. I do not see any other hints in the log files, but will post both log files that are linked to in the error message

Comment: search for the log-file of the format creation. It should be in `...,\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\lualatex`.  There should be log-files with dates as names. Show the newest.

Comment: Why do you try to use luahblatex? It should be lualatex.

Comment: I dont know, I just use the TexWorks app and select the LuaLatex + MakeIndex + BibTex option and this is the error message that shows up

Comment: does it work if you use only the lualatex compilation?

Comment: no. (I am now just reinstalling everything and see if that works)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120446/discussion-between-l-smeets-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: Your MWE works fine on my recent MikTeX.

Comment: Ok I just reinstalled everything and instead of installing MikTex just for one user I installed it for the system (against their recommendation) and now it works. Thanks.